# LXDE installed, but login screen has no option to login into LXDE

Tags: 16.04, login, desktop-environments, lxde

I am using ubuntu 16.04. However I want to use a light weight desktop environment as a backup, so I install LXDE using:

```
sudo apt install lxde
```

I install it successfully with no errors, however when I log out(even reboot) I found no option to login into LXDE environment. What shall I do next?

ps: I don't want to install `Lubuntu-desktop`.

pss: Must I install `lxdm` to use LXDE? If installed this, can my unity desktop works well?

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure you did `sudo apt install LXDE`? Commands are case-sensitive, so the correct command should have been `sudo apt install lxde`.

Comment: @edwinksl I did installed lxde, I've correct the post.

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy openbox` say? What files does `/usr/share/xsessions` contain? Is `/usr/share/xsessions/LXDE.desktop` there?

Comment: No you don't need to install lxdm. Actually lxde-core and lxde-common should be enough to have a working lxde session (both are installed with the lxde metapackage). Maybe you need to reboot so that the lxde session is detected. You can also try `sudo apt install --no-install-recommends lubuntu-core` which will give you lubuntu session with very few extra applications.

Comment: @ThanosApostolou Install lubuntu actually works, however I want unity-greeting session to login into either lxde or unity desktop itself.  Just don't feel like to install lubuntu, seems not clean enough for me...

Comment: @DKBose The first says that:  openbox:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.6.1-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
     3.6.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages

Do I have to install openbox?

Comment: @DKBose  second question: only ubuntu.desktop, how to fix this?

Comment: I would try reinstalling by `sudo apt autoremove --purge lxde lxde-core lxde-common openbox lxsession` and then `sudo apt install lxde`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Amazingly, I installed `lxsession` package and reboot, finding that I have session `lxde` and `openbox`.

However, the logout button doesn't work, so I installed `lxsession-logout`, still I can't logout.

Then I remove `lxsession-logout` and install `lxde-logout` and all works. It seems that when install `lxde-logout`, `lxsession-logout` is automatically added.

Comment: For me (on current Ubuntu 16.04), installing `lxsession-logout` *does* fix it, and package `lxde-logout` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem and here's the fix:
you need to install `lxde-common` after installing `lxde`.
it includes `lxsession` and two other packages needed for `lxde`:

```
sudo apt install lxde-common
```

I don't know why dependencies aren't covered in this particular package.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a problem with the mirror I was using (missing packages), which caused apt-get to install only some of the LXDE required packages so it thought they were all installed

After editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` and changing the repository, then `apt-get update && apt-get install lxde` worked fine